# how to set SqlMapClientTemplate from spring xml

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

I've got following java class.

```
package com.org.data.dbresource;

import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate;

public class DBConnectionManager {
    private SqlMapClientTemplate sqlMapClientTemplate;

    public void setSqlMapClientTemplate (SqlMapClientTemplate sq)
    {
        this.sqlMapClientTemplate = sq;
    }   

    public SqlMapClientTemplate getSqlMapClientTemplate ()
    {
        return this.sqlMapClientTemplate;
    }
}
```

My Spring xml looks like following:

```
 <bean id="IbatisDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/RSRC/app/oltp"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="MySqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sql-map.xml"/>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="IbatisDataSource"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="myObject" class="com.org.data.dbresource.DBConnectionManager">
    <property name="sqlMapClientTemplate" ref="MySqlMapClient"/>
 </bean>
```

Error I get  is:

> Failed to convert property value of
>   type
>   [com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl]
>   to required type
>   [org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate]
>   for property 'sqlMapClientTemplate';

Everything works fine if, instead of `SqlMapClientTemplate` I pass `SqlMapClient` but then I have to explicitly catch `SQLExceptions`

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all - you're trying to inject an object of type `SqlMapClient` (as created by `SqlMapClientFactoryBean`) into a property of type `SqlMapClientTemplate`.

You need to manually instantiate the `SqlMapClientTemplate` yourself, either inside `DBConnectionManager`, e.g.

```
private SqlMapClientTemplate sqlMapClientTemplate;

public void setSqlMapClient(SqlMapClient sqlMapClient)
{
    this.sqlMapClientTemplate = new SqlMapClientTemplate(sqlMapClient);
}
```

and then

```
<bean id="myObject" class="com.org.data.dbresource.DBConnectionManager">
   <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="MySqlMapClient"/>
</bean>
```

Remember, `SqlMapClientTemplate` isw nothing more than a helper class. Neither Spring nor iBatis mandates its use, and if you want to use it, you need to instantiate it yourself.

Comment: that is spot on. have you worked with spring before ...how do you possess such knowledge :)